# Emacs Save As with external File Manager Popup -(Linux)

Tags: linux

On some of my Linux machines, when I file-save-as, then the system file manager pops up and I can easily select destination.
On other Linux Machines, I only get the emacs internal buffer save-as, which is clunky to use for me.

I went through all the config files in emacs but could not find how to set Save-As to always use the external system file-manager.

QUESTION: How do I force emacs to always use a popup file manager during Save-As ?

Comment: By *"the emacs internal buffer save-as"*, which you find clunky, do you mean the Emacs pop-up dialog for selecting a file name, or do you mean Emacs using only the minibuffer to let you choose the file name?

Comment: Are you aware of option `use-file-dialog`? Does that fit your needs here?

Comment: I mean that I DONT want  the clunky mini-buffer,
I want the popup system  file-manager.

Answer (score 1):

Write a command that binds `use-file-dialog` to `t`, and use that command in place of `write-file`:

```lisp
(defun my-save-as-cmd filename)
 "..."
 (interactive "FSave as file...")
 (let ((use-file-dialog  t))
   (write-file filename)))

(define-key [remap write-file] 'my-save-as-cmd)
```

> `use-file-dialog` is a variable defined in `C source code'.
>
> Its value is `t`
>
> Documentation:
>
> Non-`nil` means mouse commands use a file dialog to ask for files.
>
> This applies to commands from menus and tool bar buttons even when
> they are initiated from the keyboard.  If `use-dialog-box` is `nil`,
> that disables the use of a file dialog, regardless of the value of
> this variable.
>
> You can customize this variable.

Comment: This did not help a bit.

I toggled use-dialog-box (from nil default) and save-as still gives me the clunky mini-buffer file manager.

Comment: It seems that it was saved only for that particular session. 
I just pressed every save option to try and make it global and that seems to work. 
It now opens with a pop-up window as it used to do the last 25 years of emacs use.
I find it really strange that on two identical installations on two different machines with the same emacs installed from apt repo, that one machine has emacs file-saves in mini-buffer, while the other opens an external file manager window.
Does not make sense at all.
Anyway it works now and I thank you very much for the help.